# How to make an R Shiny app reactive to re-initializing a module

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

In an R Shiny app, I created a module with the `modules` package to read (and process) external data. The module exports a function, `getData()`, which is used to access the processed data for outputting in a table. To reload/reprocess the external data, the module can be re-initialized by clicking a "Reload data" action button. How do I introduce the necessary reactivity in the minimal example below to update the table after the external data was reloaded? Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(modules)
library(utils)

# external data file needed for demonstration
#  data <- data.frame(x=999)
#  write.csv(data, "data.csv")
# 
# change 999 in csv file to a different value while the app is running and click the
# 'Reload data' button

data_mod <- module({
  
  import("utils")
  export("getData")
  data <- read.csv("data.csv")
  message(data)
  getData <- function() data
  
})


ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Reload data"),
  tableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$do, {
    id <- showNotification("Reading data...", duration = NULL, closeButton = FALSE)
    on.exit(removeNotification(id), add = TRUE)
    modules::use(data_mod, attach = TRUE, reInit = TRUE)
  })

  modules::use(data_mod, attach = TRUE, reInit = FALSE)
  
  output$myTable <- renderTable({
    getData()
  })  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Additional context: There is a large amount of processing of external data going on in the actual app, which is why I avoided doing the data processing inside the server function. The goal is to process the data only once at startup for all clients, but to allow for a manual data refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The `getData()` function needs to read the cvs file in order to re-read the file when function is called.  According to the [scooping rules](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/scoping/) in shiny, the objects declared outside the `server` function are visible across all sessions, so you can declare your data object there and update it on click by using the `<<-` assignment.

```
library(shiny)
library(modules)
library(utils)

# external data file needed for demonstration
#  data <- data.frame(x=999)
#  write.csv(data, "data.csv")
#
# change 999 in csv file to a different value while the app is running and click the
# 'Reload data' button

data_mod <- module({
  import("utils")
  export("getData")
  #data <- read.csv("data.csv")
  #message(data)
  getData <- function() read.csv("data.csv")
})

across_session_data <- data_mod$getData()

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Reload data"),
  tableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    id <- showNotification("Reading data...", duration = NULL, closeButton = FALSE)
    on.exit(removeNotification(id), add = TRUE)
    across_session_data <<- data_mod$getData()
  })

  output$myTable <- renderTable({
    input$do
    across_session_data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The actual data_mod pulls a lot of data from several APIs; I'd like to do that once on startup, keep the app active on the server, and share the data across sessions--doing the data pull for every session would be too costly. But I'd like to have the option of a manual refresh triggered by a user because occasionally an API call fails to return data.

Comment: Ah, yes of course you need the data to be shared across all sessions. I edited my answer to take that into account. See if this is more what you were looking for.